# Which offsets does the "offSize" field in a CFF font header apply to?

Tags: fonts, file-format, compact-font-format

The ["Compact Font Format Specification"](https://adobe-type-tools.github.io/font-tech-notes/pdfs/5176.CFF.pdf) explains (on page 13) that the `offSize` field in the header "specifies the size of all offsets (0) relative to the start of CFF data."  Various offsets are mentioned in the document, but most (all?) of them either have their own, separate `offSize` field (e.g. in table 7 on page 12) or they are encoded as dict data operands (e.g. the `charset` field in the Top DICT, in table 9 on page 15).

Which offsets actually use the `offSize` field from the header?

Comment: You might want to check the [FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/developer.html) implementation of CFF, which Adobe has contributed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the hint from Peter Constable's comment: The FreeType implementation of CFF reads the `offSize` field, but then just checks the value for validity and does not even store it for later use.  From this I assume that this field is just some odd (historical?) artefact, and is not actually used.

The code in question is in the file [`src/cff/cffload.c`, starting at line 2243](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/freetype/freetype/-/blob/94cb3a2eb96b3f17a1a3bd0e6f7da97c0e1d8f57/src/cff/cffload.c#L2243).  The variable `absolute_offset` corresponds to `offSize` in the spec:

```
{
  FT_Byte  absolute_offset;


  if ( FT_READ_BYTE( absolute_offset ) )
    goto Exit;

  if ( font->version_major != 1 ||
       font->header_size < 4    ||
       absolute_offset > 4      )
  {
    FT_TRACE2(( "  not a CFF font header\n" ));
    error = FT_THROW( Unknown_File_Format );
    goto Exit;
  }
}
```

**Update.** I just discovered that the `offSize` field has been removed in [version 2 of the CFF format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cff2#6-header).  This is another hint that the field may be unused.